# I am struggling to see what is wrong with my quicksort implementation

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I am struggling to see what is wrong with this quicksort implementation...

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var sortArray = function(nums) {
    return quicksortWrapper(nums);
};

let quicksortWrapper = function(nums) {
    quicksort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    return nums;
}

let quicksort = function(arr, lp, rp) {
    if (lp < rp) {
        let pivot = partition(arr, lp, rp);
        quicksort(arr, lp, pivot - 1);
        quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, rp);
    }
}

let partition = function(arr, lp, rp) {
    let pivot = rp;
    for (let i = lp; i < rp; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[pivot]) {
            swap(arr, lp, i);
            i++;
            lp++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr, lp, pivot);
    return lp;
}

let swap = function(arr, l, r) {
    let temp = arr[l];
    arr[l] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = temp;
}
```

With an input of [9,12,2,0], the code outputs [0,9,2,12], but should output [0,2,9,12].
I have figured out that the first faulty iteration is the call to quicksort([0,12,2,9], 1, 3).

Comment: First of all this is less about the algorithm than about implementation in C or C++, so why have you tagged it with the algorithm tag? You have indicated you found the first error, does this resolve your problem or is the result you are seeing after fixing the first error? If you walk through your code using the input where does it go wrong?  What have you done to isolate the problem?

Comment: @itprorh66 It is Javascript

Comment: While I think "Lomuto partition" a mistake: Is there any description of it you tried to implement? Do you see it followed to the letter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure my mistake was incrementing i inside of the for loop which already increments i at the start of each iteration.